# How to discard voice alert for 30 sec once its comes

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Am working on an android app in which i have implemented voice alert(***Text* *to*** **speech**).My issue is  Voice alerts are coming so frequently that any one gets irritated.

*So what am trying is when the first alerts comes ,the second alert should comes after 30 secIn between 30 sec if alerts comes it should simply get discarded.I tried with timer and handler both .In both the cases the alert is coming after t time interval but its not being discarded.Plz help me out.*

```
 int AlertType=0;
 final int intervalTime=300000;
 Handler handler=new handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new runnable(){
 @Override
 public void run(){
  speakWord("Activity Started");
}
},intervalTime);
```